# How to get Python to recognise file paths as strings when there are decimals and line breaks in-between directory names?

Tags: python, file, path

I have come across similar issues with writing file paths in a script.

Previously I had issues when there were `\` in between directory names, and now I am having issues with `.` in between directory names.

Is there a way to tell Python to ignore this and treat it as a file path?

For example, I have the following file path:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.2.0/bin/tesseract"
```

But the decimals at the end, i.e. `5.2.0` is not treated as a string, I believe perhaps because of the forward slash. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not treated as a string"? Are you getting any errors? If so, include them in your question. Also, explain the behaviour you are expecting and contrast that with the behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: I mean as the code stands at the moment, when I run it as a Python script, it complains that it doesn't recognise the file path, and in my interpreter I can see the decimal points in a different colour to the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to take a guess here that you have not specified the full path. The `opt` directory is usually located in the `/usr/local` directory, so try using the following path instead:

```py
"/usr/local/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.2.0/bin/tesseract"
```

If that does not work, try navigating to the file through Finder and double check that you have the correct path.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the answer. It's strange, because when I look in `/usr/local/opt/` `homebrew` is not there for some reason. Any ideas why this could be? The only folder is `anaconda3`.